# Unable to Delete Stop Word Items form ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

Hi there, I am new to c# and want to remove all the strings containing the stop words from a listbox. My code is:

```
for (int n = glossarywords.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
{
    if (glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().Contains("the "))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
    if (glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().Contains("an"))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
    if (glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().Contains(" the"))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
}
```

glossarywords is the listbox from which I want to remove those strings that contains the stop words like is, am, are, etc.
My sample data in the list box is:

```
     an accident
     accident injury
     an accident
     accident cause
     accident is
     is accident
```

beside my code it works fine if no duplicate word will occur but if a duplicate word like an accident occur it do not works! so I am new to c# can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `Items[<index>]` multiple times while deleting items from the list `glossarywords` because you have multiple if statements...

So if two statements are true, your are trying to remove the same index twice...

Either change your code to else if(s) or rework it because it is messy code to simply put all your stopwords into a list and filter your `Items` collection.

Example of how this could work:

```
var keywords = new List<string>() { "Hello", "world" };

var list = new List<string>() { "Hello", "this", "is", "the", "world" };

var removed = list.RemoveAll(p => keywords.Contains(p));
```

Edit:

Ok again, either use `else if` statements e.g.:

```
for (int n = glossarywords.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
{

    if (glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().Contains("the "))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
    else if (glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().Contains("an"))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
    else if (glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().Contains(" the"))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    }
}
```

or refactor your code to put your stopwords into a list

```
List<string> stopWords = new List<string>()
{
    "the",
    "an"
};
```

then iterator over your listview items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < glossarywords.Items.Count; i++)
{
    // get the item as string
    string itemValue = glossarywords.Items[i].ToString();

    // split the string by empty space which will separate all words
    string[] itemWords = itemValue.ToString().Split(' ');

    // check if any of the words within the current value is within the stopwords list
    if (itemWords.Any(word => stopWords.Contains(word)))
    {
        glossarywords.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

The `.Any` is a linq extension for arrays which returns true if any of the array items matches the condition...

Comment: i am not getting this solution

Comment: @user3154778 because I'm really a nice guy, I put some more examples up for you... hope this will finally help you ;)

Comment: in my case as well as in your case there is a similar bug that for the stop word An accident our both code do nothing for this stop word

Comment: @user3154778, in your comment you said "An accident" doesn't work. Did you mean to put the uppercase 'A'? In that case you can just call `glossarywords.Items[n].ToString().ToLower().Contains("an")`